# How to test Blueprints registered in different Scopes

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, pytest

I have a simple app in Flask that has blueprints that are only registered in particular scopes when in production.

```py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.register_blueprint(ping, url_prefix="/")

    if os.getenv("SCOPE") == "scope1":
        app.register_blueprint(b1, url_prefix="/b1")
    if os.getenv("SCOPE") == "scope2":
        app.register_blueprint(b2, url_prefix="/b2")

    return app
```

My problem is that when I try to test those endpoints I get a 404 response because they are not registered as there is no env variable. I've tried setting the variable SCOPE on different test files using `os.environ` and `dotenv` but I couldn't get them to work.

This is one of my tests as an example

```
def test_endpoint(client):
    resp = client.post("/b1/endpoint")
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

I dont know how to define the env variables to make this work.

This is my conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you set the environment variable in your test?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I've added a test as an example but what ur asking is exactly what i dont know how to do

Comment: Well, you wrote that you tried setting the variable... Have you tried `monkeypatch.setenv`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen i tried that but it doesnt work cause by the time i patch it in the test the app has already started and the blueprints have already been registered

Comment: Have you tried to set the variable in a session scoped fixture? I'm not sure at what point the app is created (e.g. when the `client` fixture is created) so it may or may not work.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen i've added my conftest thats when i create the app

Comment: Ok, this make it easier - I added an answer, check if that suites you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the environment variable in the same fixture that creates the app:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("SCOPE", "scope1")
    yield create_app()
```

If you want to have different scopes in different tests, you parametrize the fixture instead:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app(request, monkeypatch):
    scope = request.param if hasattr(request, "param") else "scope1"
    monkeypatch.setenv("SCOPE", scope)
    yield create_app()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("app", ["scope1"], indirect=True)
def test_endpoint(app, client):
    resp = client.post("/b1/endpoint")
    ...
```

I added the check for `param`, so you that a test that is not parametrized uses a default scope (in this case, "scope1").

This could also be helpful, if you want to run the same test with different scopes:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("app", ["scope1", "scope2"], indirect=True)
def test_endpoint(app, client):
    resp = client.post("/b1/endpoint")
    ...
```

Comment: i like your idea but i cant get it to work. The part where u do mark.parametrize is giving me the error "function uses no fixture 'scope'"

Comment: Sorry, I had a couple of errors in the answer - have corrected them now, hopefully.